# Play framework 2.0. Use alternative application.conf in test

Tags: testing, configuration, playframework-2.0

my Play using mysql in production. But I am trying to use memory for testing.

I created 2 conf file, 1 is application.conf, the other is application.test.conf (in the same directory).

I tried to do

```
play -Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf test-only
```

But it still use the default conf file. 
I'm just wonder if anyone know how to use a different conf file during testing. (or at least use a different database setting during testing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for unit tests then just add

```
running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) { Test code... }
```

to your tests and they will be done in memory. No need to change conf files.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify for other people. The syntax you gave is for Scala. In java, it's running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), new Runnable() {

Comment: Ah yeah. Well I had a 50/50 chance to get the language right ;)

Comment: However if the production database is, say for example, MySQL, shouldn't we be running tests against a MySQL database to ensure there are no database specific bugs?? Especially if you're writing straight SQL via Anorm or similar.

Comment: Pete, yes that can be an issue. It depends on how complicated your db structure is. But my experience is that you can do very much this way without running into trouble.

Comment: I think this answer is rather a workaround, it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid having to specify the "additionalConfiguration" many times. Using a conf file is much cleaner.